# Collect user input from UITextField and storing it in a certain place - Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can't figure out how to make the create an account function work in my application... I have my login system set up like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAVXC.jpg The first set of strings are the passwords. The second set are the usernames. For someone to create an account that allows them to login, I have to make a string manually through the application. How can I make this function so it gets their input and places it as a string **as long as** the same username doesn't already exist? https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MJ9m.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a local database, the proper way would be to use either sqllite or core data to create your structure, then simply add/remove users.

For an sql tutorial for ios follow this:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-tutorial-for-ios-making-our-app

Or go to this site and check the section that says "Saving and Loading Data"

http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials

I personally prefer core data because its the most complete solution once you get used to setting it up.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are asking is a persistent data, `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue: forKey:]` will be the answer.

Once you save a data with NSUserDefaults, the data will be persistent. You can get the value with `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:]`

***Added***

I misunderstood your question. In this case you should use local database as Chiques said.

Core Data will be the answer.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started

Comment: no its not, user defaults are NOT supposed to be used as a database, they are supposed to be used to store configuration and preferences.

Comment: @Chiquis I don't think it's about database. It's just for one single id/password set. I always use this as auto login thing. Isn't what Juilan asking?

Comment: read the question again, its not a single id password, is many passwords + the ability to create new accounts.

Comment: @Chiquis Will apple accept my application and approve it if I use something like core data?

Comment: @Julian of course, core data is apple's suggested way to handle databases and stuff like that, just be mindful that it is NOT that simple at first, once you understand how it works it is very easy. Follow the steps on the tutorial to get an idea of what to do.

Comment: Thank you so much for everything! :)